# what are prepackaged character stream classes?

Tags: java, io

While reading Java Tutorials, the topic Basic I/o says, use `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` when there are no `prepackaged character stream classes`.

1)What are `Pepackaged character  stream classes`?
Does it mean, a file already has some text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is quite vague and doesn't really seem to be defined anywhere, so good question.

As best I understand it it means things like `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream`, etc. Classes that have wrapped up a particular kind of stream for you and provide the functionality required to work with it.

Note that most of these streams are working with `character`s not `byte`s, and that is generally what you want in Java for dealing with `String` data in files. On the other hand though if you are reading a pure binary source then the data will come in as `byte`s and you can then use `InputStreamReader` to convert those `byte`s to `character`s.

So a prepackaged stream reader is one that already provides you the data pre-packaged in the form that you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it to mean classes which inherit `Reader` or `Writer`. Such classes "wrap" byte streams so as to convert them automatically to character streams. Example: `FileReader`, `FileWriter`; they can read text from files directly.

If no such classes exist for your particular stream needs but you know what you get out of it/put into it is text, then you must use these two wrapper classes.

Classical example: HTML. It is text, but what you get from sockets is byte streams; if you want to read it as HTML, use a `Reader` (with the correct encoding!) over the socket stream (but of course, many APIs today don't require you to do that).